# Is it possible to audit dictionary changes on UniVerse?

Tags: universe, u2, rocket-u2

A while ago, International Spectrum posted [a great article](http://www.intl-spectrum.com/resource/310/Auditing-Database-Changes-with-UniVerse-Indexing-Subroutines.aspx) that outlined the process of auditing changes in a file through the use of an indexing subroutine. This works well for record changes and I have been thinking that it would be especially useful if I could track changes to dictionaries in a file. Has anyone found a way to do this?

The record changes work thanks to a special dictionary in the file that is indexed:

`CREATE.INDEX MYFILE AUDIT.RECORDS NO.NULLS`

For dictionary auditing to work, it would be necessary to index the dictionary itself, which I don't think I can do. Is there a way to add it to the VOC or some other strategy entirely?

```
>CREATE.INDEX
File name:   DICT MYFILE
Index name(s):  AUDIT.DICT

Cannot find field name AUDIT.DICT in file dictionary or VOC, no index created.
>
```

My goal is to write dictionary changes to flat files for windows-friendly backups and possible integration with version control. I'm curious to hear if anyone has any ideas. Thanks!

*(We're running UniVerse version 11.2.4 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and we still default to PICK flavor on our main accounts.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can make a VOC pointer to a dictionary like this:

F
D_MYFILE
DICT.DICT

And treat your dictionary like a file. 
UniVerse 11.2 also has some built in Audit Logging capabilities you can read about in Chapter 7 of the UniVerse Security Features manual: http://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20%2Funiverse%2Fv11.2.4%2Funiverse_securityfeaturesusersguide_v1124.pdf